# Stop quart from Logging

Tags: logging, quart

I am trying to disable all console output from quart. According to their site it works this way:

```
from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'loggers': {
        'quart.app': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
        },
    },
})
```

or

```
from logging import getLogger
from quart.logging import default_handler

getLogger('quart.app').removeHandler(default_handler)
```

or

```
logging.getLogger('quart.serving').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.getLogger('quart.app').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

But none of them actually disable the ouput. So how can it be done?

Comment: managed to make it happen with logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL), although its suboptimal

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fully figure this out either, but a more satisfactory solution could be to run your script directly with [hypercorn](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/hypercorn/index.html) and pass `--access-logformat ""`